# Skyrim ` Can I use a hp keyboard on ps3?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Im able to plug in keyboard and mouse, but not able to use in-game.

I currently use a controller and i play on tv.

any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console versions of Skyrim do not support the PC console commands that you can normally access using the ~ or ` key.

Regardless of whether you are playing on your PS3 console with a key board or a controller, these features are not accessible on any console. They are only accessible on the PC version of Skyrim.